# Running Flutter app from IDEs using run/debug button stuck at launch/splash screen

Tags: android, ios, flutter, xcode, visual-studio-code

When I run my Flutter app by running `flutter run` with an iOS simulator, it runs correctly. However, when I use the run/debug button, it does not work:

1. The iOS simulator gets stuck at the launch screen (default blank screen).
2. The "Running Xcode build" keeps running and does not disappear: [image: There is a warning about "Running Xcode build" that does not disappear]
3. However, the Debug Console shows `Xcode build done.`

This is not unique to vscode, I see the same thing happening in Android Studio. It is also not unique to iOS simulator.