# Flutter hot-reload for flutter run

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, terminal

I understand that I can use the IDE's run/debug button to run the app, where I can perform a hot-reload by clicking on the hot-reload button.

However, I am currently only able to run the Flutter app by running `flutter run` (See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77647394/running-flutter-app-from-ides-xcode-and-android-studio-using-run-debug-button)). Online resources say that I can press `r` in the terminal where I ran `flutter run` to hot-reload the app, but when I do so, all it does is adding the letter `r` to the buffer in the terminal. I am using zsh.

Comment: How does this question differ from the original? Could you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: @MaLa What do you mean by "the original"? The problem is pressing r in the terminal where I ran "flutter run" does not trigger a hot reload, instead it just adds the letter "r" to the buffer in the terminal.

Comment: You have posted 2 similar questions. So I was thinking what is the difference and what more details should we check from the other question? Things like what terminal you are using and a screenshot of the problem could help.

Comment: @MaLa They are related, but I wouldn't say they are similar. This one is on why hot-reload by typing "r" after running flutter run does not work (btw I am using zsh, just added this to the question description). The linked question is about flutter run & the IDE run/debug button behaving differently. I have actually figured out that the issue in the linked question is related to not setting NO_PROXY (I don't want to go into too much detail here. Will post more details under that question when I get a chance.)